# How to swap the roll and pitch of a quaternion?

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I'm writing code that receives quaternion values that are used to rotate a 3D model. To display the model with the correct rotation, though, I'll need to swap the roll and pitch (rotation about the x and y axes). Since I can't change the code that produces the input quaternion, is it possible to swap the roll and pitch of a quaternion? I would like to do this without converting the quaternion to Euler angles to avoid issues if the pitch is 90 degrees.

Comment: The vector component of a quaternion defines the axis of rotation. It's length is 1. If you only use rotations around the axes of a normal coordinate system, only one vector component will be 1 and the remaining two components will be 0. So you should be done by selecting a different component to be set to 1.

Comment: Is there perhaps a faulty assumption here that the way to deal with the source having different basis vectors from the output is “to swap roll and pitch”?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the the actual issue is that you want to use different basis vectors than your source, compose the transform `A` which rotates 90 degrees around z, and possibly also inverts one, such that the x and y axes are reversed.

Then to use the supplied quaternion which represents the unknown transform, `B`, just compose:

```
C = A . B . C^-1
```

i.e. so that your net transform has the effect of:

1. adjust your input so that its axes match those assumed by the source of `B`;
2. apply `B`; and
3. adjust back from the world as known to the source of `B` to the one you want.

Comment: I think this only works if yaw is 0

Comment: Can you explain why? Can you construct a failing case? It’s a bit weird — and extremely error-prone — to try to model rotations as pitch/yaw/roll as against global axes, even just mentally, to the extent that it’s difficult to think of any scenario where the actual problem is as you describe. If it really is just that you’re using different basis vectors, with x and y transposed for both local and global coordinates, then this is correct.

Comment: If I convert the input quaternion to Euler angles, swap the roll and pitch, convert back to a quaternion, and rotate the model, the model is displayed with the correct orientation. The issue is if the pitch is 90 degrees, converting to Euler angles and back may result in an incorrect orientation.

Comment: I feel we’re not actually having a conversation here; I stand by this as the correct answer and remain unclear about the source of your doubt or the actual problem that prompted the query. Good luck with your other answers.